# how to make data exponential using gnu plot

Tags: plot, graph, gnu, gretl

so, I need to make y axis be exponential and also my observation should be exponential too. Here is code

```
set yrange[2.8:4.2]


# forecasts with 95 pc conf. interval
plot \
'-' using 1:2 title "log_m" w lines lw 0.5, \
'-' using 1:2 title "forecast" w lines, \
'-' using 1:2:3 title "95-interval" w errorbars




2019.333333 3.496507561 
2019.416667 3.433987204 
2019.5 3.465735903
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to make data exponential